# `in` defined for generator

Tags: python, python-3.8

Why is `in` operator defined for generators?

```py
>>> def foo():
...     yield 42
... 
>>> 
>>> f = foo()
>>> 10 in f
False
```

What are the possible use cases?

I know that `range(...)` objects have a `__contains__` function defined so that we can do stuff like this:

```
>>> r = range(10)
>>> 4 in r
True
>>> r.__contains__
<method-wrapper '__contains__' of range object at 0x7f82bd51cc00>
```

But `f` above doesn't have `__contains__` method.

Comment: Python developers documents their design decisions (and discussions) using their PEPs, which you can browse online. I'd guess that generators were added in early Python 2, like perhaps 2.4, as a start.

Comment: What do you mean by "Why"? Seems like `in` on a generator simply attempts to consume it until it either finds the element and returns True, or the generator runs out in which case False is returned. That seems like a very intuitive, expected behavior from a generator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"What are the possible use cases?" To check if the generator will produce some value.

Dunder methods serve as *hooks* for the particular syntax they are associated with. `__contains__` isn't some kind of one-to-one mapping to `x in y`. The language ultimately defines the semantics of these operators.

From the [documentation of membership testing](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-details), we see there are several ways for `x in y` to be evaluated, depending on various properties of the objects involved. I've highlted the relevant one for generator objects, which do not define a `__contains__`  but are iterable, i.e., they define an `__iter__` method:

> The operators in and not in test for membership. `x in s` evaluates to
> `True` if x is a member of s, and False otherwise. `x not in s` returns
> the negation of `x in s`. All built-in sequences and set types support
> this as well as dictionary, for which in tests whether the dictionary
> has a given key. For container types such as list, tuple, set,
> frozenset, dict, or collections.deque, the expression x in y is
> equivalent to `any(x is e or x == e for e in y)`.
>
> For the string and bytes types, `x in y` is `True` if and only if `x` is a
> substring of `y`. An equivalent test is `y.find(x) != -1`. Empty strings
> are always considered to be a substring of any other string, so `"" in "abc"` will return True.
>
> For user-defined classes which define the `__contains__()` method, x in
> y returns `True` if `y.__contains__(x)` returns a true value, and `False`
> otherwise.
>
> **For user-defined classes which do not define **contains**() but do
> define `__iter__()`, `x in y` is `True` if some value `z`, for which the
> expression `x is z or x == z` is true, is produced while iterating over
> `y`. If an exception is raised during the iteration, it is as if in
> raised that exception.**
>
> Lastly, the old-style iteration protocol is tried: if a class defines
> `__getitem__()`, `x in y` is `True` if and only if there is a non-negative integer index `i` such that `x is y[i] or x == y[i]`, and no lower integer
> index raises the IndexError exception. (If any other exception is
> raised, it is as if in raised that exception).
>
> The operator `not in` is defined to have the inverse truth value of in.

To summarize, `x in y` will be defined for objects that:

1. Are strings or bytes, and it is defined as a substring relationship.
2. types that define `__contains__`
3. types that are iterators, i.e. that define `__iter__`
4. the old-style iteration protocol (relies on `__getitem__`)

Generators fall into 3.

A broader point, you really shouldn't use the dunder methods directly, unless you really understand what they are doing. Even then, it may be best to aviod it.

It usually isn't worth trying to be credible or succinct by using something to the effect of:

```
x.__lt__(y)
```

Instead of:

```
x < y
```

You should at least understand, that this might happen:

```
>>> (1).__lt__(3.)
NotImplemented
>>>
```

And if you are just naively doing stuff like `filter((1).__lt__, iterable)` *then you've probably got a bug*.

Comment: Generators would fall into category 3, no?

Answer (score 2):

Generators are iterable, and so have an `.__iter__` method, which can be used to check membership

How this behaves is described in the [Expressions docs on Membership test operations](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-operations)

> For user-defined classes which do not define [`__contains__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__) but do define [`__iter__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iter__), `x in y` is `True` if some value `z`, for which the expression `x is z or x == z` is true, is produced **while iterating over y**. If an exception is raised during the iteration, it is as if [`in`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#in) raised that exception.

Emphasis mine!

This pops the whole generator, and your example with `42` simply doesn't include the tested value of `10`

```py
>>> def foo():
...     yield 5
...     yield 10
...
>>> f = foo()
>>> 10 in f
True
>>> 10 in f
False
```